# Spring Cloud Gateway /gateway/refresh endpoint does not refresh routes

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

Spring Cloud Gateway has /gateway/refresh endpoint to update the routes. When we configure actuator and run the above endpoint, it return 200 OK, but the route configurations aren't reloaded from Spring Cloud Config.

Here is the configuration:

```
management:
  endpoint:
    gateway:
      enabled: true
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: gateway
```

When we expose the actuator refresh endpoint and run actuator/refresh, the route configurations are reloaded without any issue. Here

```
management:
  endpoint:
    gateway:
      enabled: true
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: gateway,refresh
```

When i just hit /gateway/refresh endpoint it doesn't appear to do anything, but when I hit the /actuator/refresh endpoint the routes get reloaded from Spring Cloud Config into Spring Cloud Gateway.

What is the use of the /gateway/refresh endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to refresh the routes with the below configuration.

application.yml

```
 management:
      endpoint:
        gateway:
          enabled: true
      endpoints:
        web:
          exposure:
            include: "gateway"
```

Request to cloud gateway server

```
POST: http://<server>:<port>/actuator/gateway/refresh
```

Answer (score -1):

```
/gateway/refresh
```

is used for gateway routes refresh